# Flutter crash iOS - NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, crash, crashlytics

Does anyone know what this crash is? I looked it up online and some results seemed to be similar but not the exact same. Here are the traces in Crashlytics:

Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException -[__NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range {19, 9223372036854775788} out of bounds; string length 0

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1b3d19344 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1b3a2ecc0 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1b3d72550 -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:].cold.1
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1b3d72650 -[__NSCFString hasPrefix:].cold.1
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1b3bf7c0c -[_CFXNotificationNameRegistration find:observer:matching:]
5  UIKitCore                      0x1b7cfece8 -[UIResponder(UITextInput_Internal) _rangeOfText:endingAtPosition:]
6  UIKitCore                      0x1b7c68ab0 -[UIKeyboardImpl applyAutocorrection:]
7  UIKitCore                      0x1b7c5c9c0 -[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrection:executionContextPassingTIKeyboardCandidate:]
8  UIKitCore                      0x1b7c5bd58 -[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrectionForWordTerminator:executionContextPassingTIKeyboardCandidate:]
9  UIKitCore                      0x1b7c5bc10 __56-[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrectionForWordTerminator:]_block_invoke
10 UIKitCore                      0x1b7c84188 -[UIKeyboardTaskEntry execute:]
11 UIKitCore                      0x1b7c82af0 -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread]
12 UIKitCore                      0x1b7c8317c -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue addAndReturnTask:]
13 UIKitCore                      0x1b7c8366c -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue performSingleTask:]
14 UIKitCore                      0x1b7c5bb1c -[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrectionForWordTerminator:]
15 UIKitCore                      0x1b7c5eddc -[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrection]
16 UIKitCore                      0x1b7c43bf0 -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:]
17 UIKitCore                      0x1b791bfa0 -[UIInputResponderController _reloadInputViewsForKeyWindowSceneResponder:]
18 UIKitCore                      0x1b791b7b8 -[UIInputResponderController _reloadInputViewsForResponder:]
19 UIKitCore                      0x1b7e7037c -[UIResponder _finishResignFirstResponder]
20 UIKitCore                      0x1b7e70470 -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder]
21 UIKitCore                      0x1b82fb058 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _removeFirstResponderFromSubtree]
22 UIKitCore                      0x1b82fb564 __UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview
23 UIKitCore                      0x1b82fb3ac -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview]
24 Flutter                        0x100555898 (Missing)
25 Flutter                        0x1005550cc (Missing)
26 Flutter                        0x100554e40 (Missing)
27 Flutter                        0x100a97e20 (Missing)
28 Flutter                        0x1005675bc (Missing)
29 Flutter                        0x10083a108 (Missing)
30 Flutter                        0x100570af4 (Missing)
31 Flutter                        0x1005727b0 (Missing)
32 CoreFoundation                 0x1b3c953a8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
33 CoreFoundation                 0x1b3c950c0 __CFRunLoopDoTimer
34 CoreFoundation                 0x1b3c94740 __CFRunLoopDoTimers
35 CoreFoundation                 0x1b3c8f538 __CFRunLoopRun
36 CoreFoundation                 0x1b3c8ebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
37 GraphicsServices               0x1be0705cc GSEventRunModal
38 UIKitCore                      0x1b7e41744 UIApplicationMain
39 Runner                         0x1000c9804 main + 6 (AppDelegate.swift:6)
40 libdyld.dylib                  0x1b3b0b384 start
```

and Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
SIGABRT ABORT 0x00000001b3b00df0

```
Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  Runner                         0x1000e2fec CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4303040492
1  Runner                         0x1000e33d4 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4303041492
2  Runner                         0x1000d2c4c CLSHandler + 4302974028
3  Runner                         0x1000e15f0 __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 4303033840
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b39bb5ac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b39c8360 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 60
6  Runner                         0x1000e105c CLSExceptionRecord + 4303032412
7  Runner                         0x1000e0e88 CLSExceptionRecordNSException + 4303031944
8  Runner                         0x1000e0a7c CLSTerminateHandler() + 4303030908
9  libc++abi.dylib                0x1b3ad340c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x1b3ad6160 __cxa_rethrow + 148
11 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1b3a2ee84 objc_exception_rethrow + 44
12 CoreFoundation                 0x1b3c8ec38 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 592
13 GraphicsServices               0x1be0705cc GSEventRunModal + 164
14 UIKitCore                      0x1b7e41744 UIApplicationMain + 1936
15 Runner                         0x1000c9804 main + 6 (AppDelegate.swift:6)
16 libdyld.dylib                  0x1b3b0b384 start + 4
```

It seems to be something to do with an EditText (this crash happens on my login screen), but I can't figure out what. Only 1 device is affected - an XS Max on 13.6.1. No other XS Max devices or other devices on 13.6.1 are affected, just this one, maybe its due to a device configuration or something? Any ideas would be helpful.

On a side note, is there a way to get more readable logs from Crashlytics? Like maybe get the exact error Flutter would throw on a Debug app? I have no experience with Swift so the logs from iOS make no sense to me. Thanks!

Comment: From the message it says your string length is 0 but you are trying to get a substring from it which does not make sense.

Comment: @DuyNguyen that's the thing - I'm not actually getting a substring anywhere in my dart code. That's why I feel this is a Flutter error rather than specific to my app.